# React Native array.map won't sum a state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i'm working on a corona data app for school and I want to sum the amount of tests and positive results from an API.

Here is my code:

```
function GetDataApi() {
if(data !== null) {
    const filter = data?.filter((item => item.Date_of_statistics === '2021-04-01'));
    filter.forEach((item, index) => {
        setUseTestedResult(parseInt(useTestedResult) + parseInt(item.Tested_with_result));
        setUsePositiveData(parseInt(usePositiveData) + parseInt(item.Tested_positive));
    });
}
```

}

It only returns the numbers of the last object in the array. It looks like the setState function isn't working.

Comment: Please don't use `.map()` for simple iteration. Use `.forEach()` or an actual loop.

Comment: Okay I did it, but I still get the same result.

Comment: Wait, if you want to sum everything, don't you need to sum it *first*, then call `setX`?

Comment: What I want is that the variable useTestedResult and usePositiveData get summed from 0 + item.Tested_with_result every time the forEach loops. so useTestedResult is first 0 then as an example it becomes 20 + item.Tested_with_result till the forEach stops

Comment: `useTestedResult` and such are **very** strange names for state members. They look like the names of hooks (functions). They should be simple names saying what data they contain. For instance, `testsWithResults` (with the setter `setTestsWithResults`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

State updates are asynchronous. You're repeatedly updating your state, overwriting previous updates, so you end up storing only the result of the **last** call to your state setters.

Instead, build the sum, then set the result:

```
function GetDataApi() {
    if (data !== null) {
        // No ? here −−−−−−−−−−−−v
        const filteredData = data.filter((item => item.Date_of_statistics === '2021-04-01'));
        let testedSum = 0;
        let positiveSum = 0;
        for (const {Tested_with_result, Tested_positive} of filteredData) {
            testedSum += Tested_with_result;
            positiveSum += Tested_positive;
        }
        setUseTestedResult(previousValue => previousValue + testedSum);
        setUsePositiveData(previousValue => previousValue + positiveSum);
    }
}
```

A couple of notes:

- I've removed the `parseInts`, hopefully the data you're using is *already* numeric, but add them back if you need them. Only parse strings, don't call `parseInt` on numbers.
- Note that I replaced the optional chaining (`?.`) with normal chaining (`.`), since you've just tested that `data` isn't `null` and if it's `undefined`, your subsequent code would fail anyway.
- Your code was **adding** the sum from `data`'s entries to the existing state member's value, so that's what I've done above, using the callback form of the state setters (since any time you use existing state to set new state, you should use the callback form). But to me it seems a bit odd to be *adding* this information to an existing state member, rather than replacing it.